# using conditionals in SSRS for visibility

Tags: ssrs-2008, visibility, conditional-statements

In a SSRS (BIDS) 2008 report that I have created, I have a conditional statement I'm trying to use to determine the Visibility of items in a column.

An expression almost identical to this works on the General tab, but not on the Visibility tab. I get the following error when trying to preview the report

> An error occurred during local report processing. The Hidden
>   expression used in textbox 'Status' returned a data type that is not
>   valid.

I have pasted the conditional below for your reference. Do the rules/formatting for Visibility expressions differ from those of the General tab? Thanks!

```
=IIf(Fields!tagname.Value="3981.CompA1.Bool.CompA1StatusOnline"
And Fields!Status.Value="0","True",
iif(Fields!tagname.Value="3981.CompA1.Bool.CompA1StatusFaulted"
And Fields!Status.Value="1","True",
iif(Fields!tagname.Value="3981.CompA1.Bool.CompA1StatusOffline"
And Fields!Status.Value="0","True","False")))
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the formatting code? I have found that in certain circumstances when pasting expressions that ssrs likes to add something like =Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateFormat() instead of =DateFormat(). I do not know if this is a bug but I have received the same error you reported when I did this. Also, try true instead of "true".

Comment: Thanks! I know it had to be something stupid. It was the quotation marks around true and false. As soon as I removed the double quotes, it worked as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `true` instead of `"true"`.